# How to add to the list only 1 line from a text file for verifying content and after to move to next line?

Tags: python-3.x

The problem is a survey about what is the favourite colour. every line has 3 colours separated by space "blue yellow green". First is first place , 2nd is second place and 3rd is 3rd place. So after going over the text I must print some like "blue(1,0,0) , yellow(0,1,0), green(0,0,1). I need to return this as a tuple so I thought to convert List into tuple after I will have final result of survey.
I thought to add the Line to the list and after to iterate through the list to see what colours I have on what place.  I just started to learn Python so I'm pretty bad on it. If anyone have better ideas please let me know.
Thanks A Lot!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGIfQ.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! We prefer if you could provide your code as text (formatted as a code block) instead of an image, so it's easier for others to view and run it, and avoids broken links in the future. Also, you should consider rephrasing your title; right now it's not very descriptive of the problem.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you're asking exactly. Some clarification would help. Are you trying to return a list/tuple of tuples of 3 elements for every line of your file? You can use `tuple(a_list)` if you want to convert a list into a tuple.